# module dependency with ngRoute breaks angular rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, ngroute

I am trying to use Mean stack in my website project. I am using ngRoute for routing and I want to add bootstrap carousel to my main page. I am trying to put angular team carousel component from this [page](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

While I am trying to implement this, I realize as soon as I try to add module dependency ( which is var app = angular.module('myApp'**, []**) ) to my controller , angular breaks (without any error) and nothing appear in page. If I delete, everything is working normal. I assume this is related with routing ?

Project Structure;

```
-myApp
    -node_modules
    package.json
    server.js
    -public
        -controllers
        -lib
        -views
        app.js
        index.html
```

## app.js ;

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module('filmSevmem', ['ngRoute']);

  app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
      .when('/main', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainController'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutController'
      })
      .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
        controller: 'ContactController'
      })
      .otherwise({redirectTo:'/main'});
  });

})();
```

## MainController.js;

```
(function(){

  var app = angular.module('myApp');

  var MainController = function ($scope, $http) {

  ....... // codes from carousel
  .......


  app.controller('MainController', MainController);

})();
```

If I add , [] or ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'] or anything to right of 'myApp', nothing work and I get empty page from my localhost. What can cause this problem ? What should I do ? Thank you.

Comment: can you provide working sample on plunkr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var app = angular.module('myApp');` means get me the module myApp.`var app = angular.module('myApp', [listOfDependencies]);` means create the module myApp with all of the listed dependencies. So if you put square brackets in `app.js` AND in `mainController.js`, then you overwrite the previously created. The simplest solution would be to add `ngAnimate` and `ui.bootstrap` in your `app.js` like this: `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap']);`

---

If you don't want to have all your dependencies in your root module, you can make submodules like var controllers = `angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['ngAnimate'])`, and include this in your `app.js` like `var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers']);`

Comment: I didn't know that its overwrite myApp. So how can I get ng.animate and ui.bootstrap ?

Comment: just include them in app.js like: var app = angular.module('filmSevmem', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']); And dont put brackets in mainController.js

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you for your help. I understand now how to add modules to my existing project. Thanks.

Comment: saved me hours of trouble shooting!

Answer (score 0):

Why you are creating two different modules? And even you are not injecting the first module while creating the second.

> By no chance your application is gonna work until and unless you code everything using single module or inject one module in another!